# Why shouldn't you use a global variables for the Selenium webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, global-variables

As I am new to OO programming this may seem a trite question.

I am trying to write a basic End-User testing framework which has a class Pageobject with the majority of method code.

I have a testing script which instantiates the selenium driver at the top-level and then I have a number of Page object method calls to "do stuff".

If I instantiate the driver at the top-level then I need to pass the driver object to any method that needs it which is fine but I would like to minimise the number of parameters passed to a method call for the saake of readability.

eg. home_page.login(this_user) reads a little better than home_page.login(this_user, selenium_driver).

I know global variables are frowned upon so is there any other way that all method can have access to an object in a different scope.

Comment: it's one thing to avoid redefining globals, but it seems kind of sadistic to mandate passing it to every method. I think using a global is fine in this case. I've been doing the same thing with mechanize

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using a static instance for the driver as long as you understand the scope of a static variable.

Comment: It's fine as long as you only access the driver from one thread, only run one test at a time, and only support one browser at a time, i.e. the driver truly is global, and not just made static for short-term simplicity. Those objections might be irrelevant for you - though I'd argue that OO *done right* makes for simpler and more flexible code.

Comment: Can you initialize your `home_page` with the driver, like `home_page = HomePage.new(selenium)` and then later `home_page.login(...)`? Global context is usually a bad design decision, but sometimes you can keep the impact of them very localized, such as just within your testing environment, which can lead to cleaner code and fewer errors.

Comment: Great response peoples did not expect a response so quickly.

Comment: Great response peoples did not expect a response so quickly. (max pleaner): this is what I suspected although Andrews comments about concurrency is absolutely valid and not something I had considered. Readability or flexibility makes for interesting opposing bedfellows. (tadman):Presently I have a test-driving script which does just that, but as I stated it still requires me to pass the selenium driver to the homepage Pageobject and as stated previously by others I guess the question is how important is flexibility to me.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. Your opinions and council are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I access all my Page objects in my tests through a PageRepo class that initializes all of my Page objects.

I initialize the PageRepo class in a base class that my test classes inherit from This is also where I initialize my WebDriver.

so my tests look like this.

PageRepo.HomePage().DoSomething()

Comment: I like this idea. So you can instantiate a web-driver per test ensuring concurrency but still have a level of control over the scope of the webdriver. This maybe what tadman was alluding to. Nice, although you still have to pass the web-driver via parameter to DoSomething which was what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I also use a WebDriverFactory class that returns whatever type of driver i need(chrome,IE,whatever) that class stores the last driver it returned statically as well.